# About align two input fields

Tags: css

I have a very simple page layout which only contains a drop-down selection field and a text input field.

You can run my code [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pa4r/3/) .

I managed to make the options field and text input field looks like left align with each other by applying :

`margin-left: 60px;` to the options field.

I am wondering is there a **more flexible way** to approach **the same result**?

What I mean is my current way is limited, because the **60px margin** is defined based on my eye vision, is there any way can be more accurate to make  the two field at the same left align instead of define a fixed 60px margin?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you should contain these form fields to align accordingly, theres tons of options:

```
<p></p> (text/span)

<table></table> (table)
```

I personally like

```
<ul></ul> (list)
```

If you really want it your way, give the div container `position:relative` and the form fields an absolute position within for accuracy